# Помогите с пунктуацией

Tags: пунктуация

В связи с вышеизложенным работа является актуальной.

Comment: Помогают начинающему делать.

Answer (score 3):

Нераспространенный оборот в препозиции и в текстах делового стиля  не обособляется, но стилистику предложения нужно изменить, например:

В связи с вышеизложенным  можно сделать вывод, что тема данной работы является актуальной.